# Custom input date in html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a date field in my html page :

```
<input type="date"   id="birth_date" name="birth_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"   />
```

When I launch my application I got this result :

[image: this]

I need to know How can I hide these controls ( right of the image) using the simplest way ?

Thanks,

Comment: Check `-webkit-appearance` property, https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, there are 4 things you want to remove for `input[type=date]` on a webkit browser:

1. Blue cross
2. Up arrow button
3. Down arrow button
4. Datepicker dropdown button (opens up datepicker)

This CSS rule will hide them all:

```
input[type=date]::-webkit-clear-button, /* blue cross */
input[type=date]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, /* up */
input[type=date]::-webkit-outer-spin-button, /* down */
input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator /* datepicker*/ {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
input::-webkit-clear-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pcjvcd3e/)

Comment: No change, I got no change

Comment: It should work. You can check the JSFIDDLE demo I posted now.

Comment: I got different result when I change the browser. even using your demo

Comment: Maybe you should try -moz-appearance in case you are using firefox.